# Reset a local ANNOTATION variable?

Tags: uima, ruta

I'm using an ANNOTATION variable within a BLOCK statement. How do I initialize and/or reset an ANNOTATION variable to an "empty" value?

Comment: I found a way to make it work: Create an uninitialized ANNOTATION variable and use usedAnnotation{ -> ASSIGN(usedAnnotation, uninitializedAnnotation)} to clear the value. Is there a better way?

Comment: Another way (less elegant) would be the null assignment:
`Document{-> usedAnnotation = null};`

Answer (score 0):

All variables in UIMA Ruta are global and thus are not automatically reset within a block.

As the comments of the question correctly mention, resetting the values of the variables is currently done by a separate rule at the beginning of the block using an implicit action or the `ASSIGN` action.

DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta